# total sums with n number of digits

Tags: ruby, function, loops, math, nested

so I got a bit of a stumper for you. I need to write a function that takes a number (call this K) and outputs n numbers where the sum if these numbers == K.

For instance, if I give this function (100,3) it will output [1,2,97], [1,3,96], [1,4,95]... [97,1,2]

I have the function worked out for three digits:

```
k = 100
r = []
0.upto(k/2) do |a|
    (a+1).upto(k/2) do |b|
        c = k-(a+b)
        r << [a,b,c]
    end
end
```

How would I write this function that takes an n amount of digits?

Comment: What you have doesn't really work if you're not requiring that the solutions be unique except for order. The sample solution you show of `[97,1,2]` cannot occur with the loop you have. The maximum value of each of the first two addends would be `50`. And your requirements aren't clear. Is it supposed to output *all* possible combinations of addends? Are addends required to be greater than 0?

Comment: Ack, you're completely right. This is to find unique addens that add up to k.

Comment: There are infinitely many numbers which add up to any given number. Do you want to enumerate them all?

Comment: The goal is to find N unique addens which add up to k.

Comment: If you expect to have a finite solution you'll will need to add some constraints. The most likely constraints that you have omitted are that the addends must all be >= 0, i.e negative numbers are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the best solution in the world (memory required grows with `O(k^3)`), but it's a solution. I'm welcome to suggestions for improvement.

You might be interested in reading about [integer partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29), which is what we're counting here.

You're looking for a function `f(k,n)` that will count the number of ways to partition a number `k` into exactly `n` parts. Part of the problem is it's hard to tell when you count a partition twice.

I'll solve this problem by using another function `g(k,n,s)` that counts the number of ways to partition a number `k` into `n` parts **where the maximum value allowed is** `s`. So for example, we don't count the partitions `(90,8,2)` or `(64,20,16)` in `g(100,3,60)` since they use values greater than `s=60`.

`g(k,n,s) = f(k,n)` when `s>=k` (i.e. we don't place a maximum on the values allowed in the partition).

A few facts about `g(k,n,s)`:

- `k==n` implies `g=1` since the only way to partition `k` into `k` parts is by using all `1`s (hence `s` is irrelevant since we use the lowest number possible)
- `n>k` implies `g=0` since we can't partition `k` into more than `k` parts
- `s==1` implies `g=1` if `k==n` and `g=0` otherwise, since placing a maximum value of `1` only allows a partition of `k` into `k` parts (all ones)
- `n==1` implies `g=1` if `s>=k` and `g=0` otherwise, since the only partition of `k` into `n=1` parts requires that we use `k` itself in the partition
- `s<RoundUp(k/n)` implies `g=0` since we can't partition `k` into `n` parts using values less than `k/n`; for example we can't partition `100` int o `4` pieces using only values less than `25`.
- `s>k-n+1` implies `g(k,n,s) = g(k,n,s-1)` since increasing the max value `s` after `k-n+1` doesn't add any new partitions; for example, any partition of `100` into `3` parts will never include a number greater than `100-3+1 = 98`
- `g(k,n,s) = g(k,n,s-1) + g(k-s,n-1,s)` in every other case. This just adds any partitions using a value of `s` to all the previous partitions we've counted using a maximum value of `s-1`

Now I just choose maximum number `K` and throw all these facts into a nested `for` loop and deduce every value of `g(k,n,s)`. To get `f(k,n)` I just find `g(k,n,k)`.

Here's the algorithm, not suitable for large `K`.

```
g = (K by K by K) array of all zeros

for k = 1:K
    for n = 1:K
        for s = 1:K

            if (k==n)
                val = 1;
            else if (n>k)
                val = 0;
            else if s==1
                val = int(k==n);
            else if n==1
                val = int(s>=k);
            else if s<RoundUp(k/n)
                val = 0;
            else if s>(k-n+1)
                val = g(k,n,s-1);
            else
                val = g(k,n,s-1) + g(k-s,n-1,s);
            end

            g(k,n,s) = val;

        end
    end
end
```

For `f(100,3) = g(100,3,100)` I get `833` unique partitions, which you can see is correct if you use a brute force method. Please point out mistakes if you see any.